# On the number of minimal normal subgroups w.r.t. to a maximal subgroup which is simple and non-abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and $L$ a maximal subgroup of $G$. If $L$ is non-abelian and simple, then in $G$ there exists at most two minimal normal subgroups.

What I got: Suppose we have three minimal normal subgroups $P,Q,R$. Then as $P\cap R = Q \cap R = 1$ we have $P \in C_G(R)$ and $Q \in C_G(R)$, therefore $PQ \in C_G(R)$. So I know about the centraliser of $R$ that it is i) normal in $G$, because $R$ is normal, and ii) by the above, that it is non-trivial and not a minimal normal subgroup, because $P\cap Q = 1$. So I guess I have to show somehow that the centraliser indeed has these properties for a maximal subgroup $L$ with these properties to get a contradiction, but here I have no idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ and $Q$ be minimal normal subgroups of $G$. At least one of them, say $P$, is not contained in $L$ (because $L$ is simple), so $PL=G$, Now, since $Q \cap P=1$, so $$Q \cong \frac{Q}{Q \cap P} \cong \frac{PQ}{P} \unlhd \frac{G}{P} \cong L$$
so $Q \cong L$ is nonabelian simple and hence $G = PQ \cong P \times Q$. Then $P$ must also be simple, or it wouldn't be a minimal normal subgroup, and  $P$ and $Q$ are the only minimal normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ''$P$ and $Q$ are the only minimal normal subgroups'' - why that? By another theorem I know this just follows if $P$ and $Q$ are both nonabelian and simple, but I do not see why $P$ should be non-abelian...

Comment: $P$ could be abelian or nonabelian, but $P$ and $Q$ would still be the only minimal normal subgroups.

Comment: But why, for example $C_2 \times C_2$ has three minimal normal subgroups, so the factors are not the only ones...

Comment: But $Q$ is definitely nonabelian!

Comment: Okay, guess I found a proof of that fact, is this to complicated or is there any easier way to see this? My proof: Suppose $G = P\times Q$ as above and let $N\unlhd G$. If there exists no $(n_1, n_2) \in N$ with $n_2\ne 1$, then $N \le P\times \{1\}$, and by simplicity we have $N = \{1\}$ or $N = P\times\{1\}$. Otherwise there exists some $(n_1, n_2) \in N$ with $n_2 \ne 1$. Then there exists some $g_2 \in P$ with $g_2 n_2 \ne n_2 g_2$ as otherwise $Z(Q)$ would be nontrivial (using that $Q$ is nonabelian), set $g = (1,g_2)$, then $[g,n] \in N\cap Q$ and so $Q\le N$ by using simplicity...

Comment: ... Then $$NQ/Q\unlhd G/Q\cong P.$$ And so $NQ/Q = Q/Q$ or $NQ/Q = G/Q$, in the first case we have $N = NQ = Q$, in the second case we have $N = NQ = G$.

Comment: Another approach is to note that, if the minimal normal subgroup $N$ is not equal to $Q$, then $N \le C_G(Q)$ (you proved that in your post). But, since $C_G(Q) \cap Q = 1$, we must have $N= C_G(Q)$, so $N$ is uniquely detemrined - and in fact $N=P$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why was it in the answer that “$P$ must also be simple, or it wouldn’t be a minimal normal subgroup”, please?

Comment: Well if $P$ was not simple, then it would have a proper nontrivial normal subgroup $N$, which would also be normal in $G$ but then $P$ would not be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why is $N$ necessarily normal in $G$? The claim seems to be out of $G=P\times Q$ with $Q$ simple, but...I’m just precisely stuck here. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: I think you should spend more time thinking about this. (This is a 3-year old post with an accepted answer.)

Comment: @DerekHolt I’ve got it! All $g\in G$ can be written as $g=pq$, where $p\in P, q\in Q$. Now assume $N$ to be a nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $P$, $N^g=N^{pq}$; since $[P,Q]=1$, we get $N^g=N^{pq}=N^p=N$, $N$ is hence normal in $G$... as desired. It now seems pretty obvious to me, maybe I was just a bit too tired. Anyway, thank you! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @DerekHolt Hello, Professor, the OP (*StefanH*) asked in the comments that why $P$ and $Q$ are the ***only*** minimal normal subgroups of $G$. I may think it should not have been so complicated. Would you be kind enough to help me check my thoughts? Suppose $H$ to be another ***minimal normal subgroup*** of $G$, if not contained in $Q$, it must follow $H\cap Q=1$, giving $H\subseteq P$ (since $G=PQ$). Hence $H=P$. By the way, $Q$ is non-Abelian might seem useless to me, the simplicity of $Q$ could already be sufficient. Am I right in my reasoning? Thanks, and $+1$ for your nice answer!

Comment: @Math Sorry but I am just getting too many new questions as comments to old questions at the moment. You should ask it as a new question, and in any case you should not really be directing your questions at a single person.

Comment: @DerekHolt oh yes, sorry for that, thanks for your reminding me of that.